# DropDown in Kendo UI Grid showing Object-Object after selecting option from drop down list

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, dropdown, kendo-dropdown

I am using kendo grid in my application.
In that grid, I have used kendo drop down list.
I have an array for datasource of that dropdownlist.
The array looks like

```
var arr = [{text: "demo 1", value: 1}, {text: "demo 2", value: 2}]
```

My Dropdownlist Looks like:

```
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        navigatable: true,
        pageable: true,
        height: 550,
        filterable: {
            mode: "row"
        },
        sortable: {
            mode: "single",
            allowUnsort: false
        },
        toolbar: ["create"],
        columns: [
            { field: "Item", title: "Item", width: "300px", editor: categoryDropDownEditor }
        ],
        editable: true
    });

    function categoryDropDownEditor(container, options) {
        $('<input data-text-field="text" data-value-field="value" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '" />')
            .appendTo(container)
            .kendoDropDownList({
                dataSource: arr,
                autoBind: true,
                dataTextField: "text",
                dataValueField: "value",
            });
    }
```

It is showing the text in dropdown correctly but after selecting the option from drop down it shows **object object** as a selected text.

Attached the screenshot of the drop down selected value and after option after selecting
[Image of option selecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeppI.png)
and
[After option selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQfqL.png)

I have tried a lot of solutions but didn't work.
It will be great if someone provides the solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I Just Have Updated "Cara Tilos's" Jsfiddle code,

http://jsfiddle.net/0zauzskn/5/

This will give you your desired result.

I have added

```
schema: {
    model: {
        fields: {
            item: { type: "string" }
        }
    }
}
```

Into your dataSource

Best Of Luck.

Comment: Thanks for the response but that is not working because I have change dataValueField from text to value as I want to get the selected option's value to process it further.
In your fiddle it is returning text instead of value as dataValueField is mentioned as text.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `data-text-field` and `data-value-field` on your `categoryDropDownEditor`.

Made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0zauzskn/1/) for you. Check this one.

Comment: The fiddle provided by you also has same issue.
Try adding new record and then select the option from drop down. It is showing "object object"

Comment: I added a `valuePrimitive` on `kendoDropDownList`. http://jsfiddle.net/0zauzskn/6/

Comment: Thanks but adding valuePrimitive shows me the value of that option if I use dataValueField: "value" instead of "text".
I have to add dataValueField as value because I need to save it in DB.